# "Delete this answered question?" when the only answer is deleted

Tags: bug, questions, vote-to-delete

Looks like there's a small bug in the UI: I posted a question here on meta.SE which ended up being just something dumb I was doing and no use to anyone in the future. At first I posted an answer saying what the dumb thing was, but then I realized that the whole thing had no value, so I deleted the answer, and then deleted the question — whereupon it asked me:

> **Delete this answered question?**
>
> We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge.
>
> Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?

(Screenshot below)

Probably shouldn't ask (or add to the tally) if the only answers are deleted ones...

[image]

Comment: Still happening in June 2018. Close voters, please test before closing as "can no longer be reproduced". Many bugs exist for years without being fixed. /cc @ale

Answer (score 3):

What's happening here is that the warning is determined on page load - if there are answers, or the question has duplicates pointing at it, or the author is q-banned, there'll be a special warning shown if the owner tries to delete it.

If you post an answer, the page automatically reloads, and the state of the warning is recalculated.

But if you *delete* an answer, the answer just gets greyed out client-side; the page doesn't automatically refresh. So whatever warnings were calculated previously will still show.

This is probably the lesser of two evils here; waiting on a request for current warnings to complete upon requesting deletion seems excessive. Still, we could probably double-check in cases where something on the page has changed since it was loaded.