# Should the "can no longer be reproduced" off-topic close reason on meta be changed?

Tags: discussion, meta, close-reasons, off-topic

Here on Meta Stack Exchange as well as on Meta Stack Overflow, we have an off-topic close reason that says:

> The problem described here **can no longer be reproduced**. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.

This close reason was only supposed to be used for unresolved issues that are ephemeral or user-specific, or have to do with outdated features of Stack Exchange. In other words, it's a replacement for the old "too localized" close reason.

However, users seem to be using this on *every* solved bug report, especially since the wording implies it's OK to use it on such questions. However, that's not the intention of this close reason.

Thus, I think it should be changed. What should it be changed to? Please suggest. (In my answer below, I suggest splitting the close reason into two; feel free to make similar suggestions.)

Comment: "or have to do with outdated features of Stack Exchange" - Source?

Comment: @Catija Note the mass-closures under this reason of questions about April Fool's features (except in 2014, when a new specific reason was created and used, and 2013, when the former "too localized" reason was in service).

Comment: That's not really an answer to my question. *Being* used that way doesn't mean that's how it was intended to be used.

Comment: @Catija My gist still applies. I'm not exactly sure if that's how the SE team intended for the close reason to be used, but they've turned a blind eye to it later (i.e. not done the same thing they did in 2014 and temporarily create a whole new close reason for it).

Comment: They haven't though. I've specifically seen posts that are about outdated features reopened by staff because closing them for being no longer current features is wrong. And when I see them in the close review queue, I mark them as "leave open".

Comment: @Catija I've only seen questions about outdated features reopened if they contain discussion that is still relevant today. Most (e.g. April Fool's features) aren't reopened.

Comment: If you chose to downvote this, is it because you think it shouldn't be changed, or because you think we shouldn't be having this discussion? Note that an answer stating that "this shouldn't be changed" is perfectly acceptable; this isn't a feature request.

Comment: You haven't tagged it as a feature request, but it still feels like a feature request.  You're just assuming this change will happen and moving forward on that assumption.  I can see why people would downvote it for that reason alone.

Comment: @fbueckert I've edited it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not used that much; 57 times over the past 90 days. It probably *should* be used more, but I'm not too bothered by it.

I did a quick check on the last 10 questions closed. Three were probably misuses of the reason, although 1 was pretty borderline (I certainly didn't reopen it). The most blatant errors were these two:

1. [Etiquette for closing your own questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5215/etiquette-for-closing-your-own-questions)

   Closing a FAQ entry is probably reasonable in some circumstances, but... I just don't see it here. I'll chalk it up to abject carelessness.
2. ["Delete this answered question?" when the only answer is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254111/delete-this-answered-question-when-the-only-answer-is-deleted)

   This is still very much a bug and can be trivially reproduced. Either no one tried, or they didn't look at the question carefully before trying. Again, carelessness.

In both cases, the problem isn't so much the wording of the close reason... It's that the close voters were careless. So, stop being careless, and if you see a question with close votes and no obvious reason why it should be closed... Ask them to stop. Similarly, if you see a question that's already closed but shouldn't, vote to reopen it.

Comment: Here's a link to the specific questions reviewed and their outcome: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AqtMgKjEFIvOgcoev9XrLkpOB1laug

Comment: According to the revision history of the first question, the Community user locked it when it got closed. Just out of curiosity, do you know why that happened?

Comment: Yeah - that question was originally migrated from Stack Overflow, so closing it rejected the migration (locked the post here, unlocked it on SO). That's not particularly useful behavior in this case, but that's why it happened @Donald.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Also, Shog cleared the migration history at the time he reopened it, so this is why you don't see a "migrated from" or "migration rejected" entry.

Answer (score 1):

Posting my suggestion as an answer so it can be considered along with the rest.

I suggest splitting the close reason into two, for the two use cases I mentioned in my question:

> This question was caused by an **ephemeral or user-specific issue** that has since resolved itself. While such questions can be asked here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help others with the same problem. If you encounter a similar problem, please ask a new question.

I'll admit, I don't really like the wording of it; I modeled it after a Stack Overflow off-topic close reason.

For the second case, I'd create the following new reason, or if that's not possible, require such questions to be closed with custom comments instead:

> This question was asked in regards to **a deprecated or removed feature of Stack Exchange**. As the feature no longer exists, questions about it are now off-topic.

I modeled this after a close reason choice that Shog9 created and used to close Unicoins questions (questions relating to the 2014 April Fool's feature), and then removed after mass-closing them. I don't really like the wording of it either. Please propose new wordings of this, and comment on whether or not you agree with the basic gists.